# How to connect to gcloud postgres db from a container inside cloud run

Tags: postgresql, docker, gcloud

I've a container inside my cloud run that expects to receive `DATABASE_URL` variable.
I would like to connect to my existing GCP postgres db, but i just can't get it work.
I've defined a private IP on my db instance and trying to connect via this url string

```
postgres://<db-user-name>:<my-password>@<my-ip>/<my-db-name>
```

In the logs I can see that it's just stock on:

```
level=info msg="Connecting with postgres://<username>:<password>@<db-ip>/<dbname>"
```

For few minutes and then it's say:

```
level=info msg="Unable to connect to database" error="Could not Connect to SQL: dial tcp <ip>:5432: connect: connection timed out"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Share the connection url which you're using

Comment: DATABASE_URL=postgres://{user}:{password}@{hostname}:{port}/{database-name}

Comment: It's the same structure.. without the port, but I've tried also with the port it didn't worked

Comment: Please share the postgresql.conf file

Comment: The line listen_addresses = '*' in the postgresql.conf is by default commented. Be sure to uncomment it

Comment: How can I find this file in gcloud?

Comment: Using linux env?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to edit `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files.

`postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

`pg_hba.conf file`:

```
host    all         all         192.168.1.0/24        md5
```